# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (I'm not calling it?)

Tags: python, string, file, function

I'm trying to have a function write to a file with 4 different string variables passed into what is written, but for whatever reason when this is attempted, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Files\writePy\writePy.py", line 34, in <module>
    indent = writeIf(mFile, genCond(), lFile, indent)
  File "C:\Python Files\writePy\writePy.py", line 23, in writeIf
    file.write('%sif (%s %s %s):' (indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is my main code:

```
# Main code
lFile = open('OperationLog.txt', mode='w') # Log file for changes
mFile = open('Evolve.txt', mode='w+') # File to be edited
indent = 0 # Indentation for written code

# Write two IF statements with a randomized condition to file, update indentation
indent = writeIf(mFile, genCond(), lFile, indent)
indent = writeIf(mFile, genCond(), lFile, indent)

# Close files
lFile.close()
mFile.close()
```

and this is the function the error is in:

```
def writeIf(file, cond, log, indent):
    indentation = ' ' * (4 * indent) # Number of spaces to add is 4 * indent
    file.write('%sif (%s %s %s):' (indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
    indent = indent + 1
    log.write('Added: IF statement to %s.' % file.name)
    return indent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `format()` function in cases as this as its more suitable and easy to maintain

```
file.write('{0}if ({1}{2}{3}):'.format(indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
```

Answer (score 9):

You forgot the modulo operator (`%`):

```
file.write('%sif (%s %s %s):' % (indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
#                      here --^
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use string formatting:

```
file.write('%sif (%s %s %s):' % (indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
```

Without the modulo operator (%), Python interprets it indeed as a function call:

```
file.write('string'(indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Though these answers definitely address your problem, you should also be aware of the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__) #or whatever name you want, like 'my_logger'
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('OperationLog.txt', mode=w')) #default is 'a'ppend mode
```

Then your function would look like this:

```
def writeIf(file, cond, indent):
    indentation = ' ' * (4 * indent) # Number of spaces to add is 4 * indent
    file.write('%sif (%s %s %s):' % (indentation, cond[0], cond[1], cond[2]))
    indent = indent + 1
    log.debug('Added: IF statement to %s.', file.name)
    return indent
```

Comment: +1, though I think `.fileHandler` should be `.FileHandler` - minor error, but it didn't work when it was camelcased.

Comment: Good call - `FileHandler` is a class.