# Problems in python 3.x with printing with %

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a problem with `print` in python 3.x

If you remember from python 2.x, you can write code like this:

```
var = 224 
print "The var is %d" %(var)
```

and it would print out:

```
The var is 224
```

But in python 3.x it doesn't work, so who knows please help.

Comment: Your problem is not with string interpolation but with the `print` statement. In Python 3, `print()` is now a *function*.

Comment: It is recommended to use the `format()` function, see its usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19382774/2425215)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var = 224
print("The var is %d" % var)
```

Definitely have to treat print as a function with Python 3.
Try it out at: http://ideone.com/U95q0L

You could also, for a simpler solution, without interpolation, do this:

```
print("The var is", var)
```

Also included that on Ideone.

Comment: I suppose you meant `%`, not `,` in the print statement?

Comment: The `%d` only applies when using interpolation... You would just omit the argument completely in your first example... (unless you wanted a literal `%d` in there for some reason)

Comment: Yep, fixed.  Will upvote Rob's answer to alleviate guilt.  I like Python but it's been a while.

Comment: @sdanzig I'd leave in the second example - it's a more convenient way of doing it... doesn't rely on a formatting string with a type, just does it all nicely and for less characters

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a keyword which is used in a print statement. In Python 3, `print` is a function name and is used just as any other function is.

In particular, `print` requires parenthesis around its argument list:

```
 print ("The var is %d" %(var))
```

Ref: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function